# how to convert julian date(csv file) to normal date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, csv, insert-into

We have tried concatenate data in excel so as to make the insert query, but the date col got converted from 28/04/2017 to '42853'(text format) and when we inserted the data onto sql server it comes in text format.

`Name Date
Neha 28/04/2017`

but wh

Answer (score 2):

Adding the number from excel as days to the date 1899-12-30 will return a proper date.

```
select dateadd(day,42853,'18991230')
```

returns: `2017-04-28`

---

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [**`try_cast()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) to convert your text value to an integer.

```
select 
  ...
  , dateadd(day,try_cast(col as int),'18991230') 
from t
```

Prior to that, you can use `patindex()` to in a `case expression` to confirm that the column is only numbers before attempting to `cast()` if there is a chance that some columns in the text column are not numbers.

```
select 
  ... 
  , case when patindex('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',col) = 1
         then dateadd(day,cast(col as int),'18991230')
         else null
         end
from t
```